# How to make webpage respond with nothing

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make my web page respond with nothing. When it's called it calls some unimportant functions on the server side. I'd like there to be no response. Not a "blank page" response where meta data is still sent - I mean 0 bytes are sent back to the client.

Can this be done from the web page (php)? Or will I have to much around in Apache2 to make this happen?

Comment: I don't think what return 0 bytes as response is a web page. I think you should create a TCP or UDP server that is not related to Apache2 or other web servers.

Comment: But the client should get some kind of response for its request. Why do you want to not respond?

Comment: Mostly because I don't care about the client, and in this particular use case, the client doesn't actually care for a response. For all it matters, the call failed for some reason and that's completely fine. (very atypical, I know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe cannot be achieved using PHP. The web server will still send back the header information even if provide no content or abort the execution in PHP.

I would recommend to use the appropiate status code (204 - No Content) while not returning any body content. This is the expected behavior in this case (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5).

If you need to have a zero bytes response you'd need to implement a custom TCP or UDP server as suggested by MikeCAT.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly do that in PHP, because the HTTP protocol requires *something* to be sent back. At the very least, a HTTP status code.

You can *probably* (depending on your setup) reduce the output to the bare bones by clearing the output buffer and terminating the script:

```
while (ob_get_level()) { ob_end_clean(); }
$file = ""; $line = 0;
if (headers_sent($file, $line)) {
    die("DEBUG: first stop headers being sent by {$file} at line {$line}");
}
die(Header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
```